# ColdFusion adding extra quotes when constructing database queries in strings

Tags: sql, string, coldfusion, railo, cfml

I am coding in ColdFusion, but trying to stay in cfscript, so I have a function that allows me to pass in a query to run it with 

`<cfquery blah >
  #query#
</cfquery>`

Somehow though, when I construct my queries with `sql = "SELECT * FROM a WHERE b='#c#'"`  and pass it in, ColdFusion has replaced the single quotes with 2 single quotes.  so it becomes  `WHERE b=''c''` in the final query.

I have tried creating the strings a lot of different ways, but I cannot get it to leave just one quote.  Even doing a string replace has no effect.

Any idea why this is happening?  It is ruining my hopes of living in cfscript for the duration of this project

Answer (score 18):

ColdFusion, by design, escapes single quotes when interpolating variables within `<cfquery>` tags.

To do what you want, you need to use the [`PreserveSingleQuotes()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/functions_m-r_14.html) function.

```
<cfquery ...>#PreserveSingleQuotes(query)#</cfquery>
```

This doesn't address, however, the danger of SQL injection to which you are exposing yourself.

Using [`<cfqueryparam>`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Tags_p-q_18.html) also allows your database to cache the query, which in most cases will improve performance.

It might be helpful to read [an old Ben Forta column](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/ben_forta_faster.html) and [a recent post by Brad Wood](http://www.codersrevolution.com/index.cfm/2008/7/26/cfqueryparam-its-not-just-for-security-also-when-NOT-to-use-it) for more information about the benefits of using `<cfqueryparam>`.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to your question, as others have said, is using `preserveSingleQuotes(...)`

However, the *solution* you actually want, is *not* to dynamically build your queries in this fashion. It's Bad Bad Bad.

Put your SQL inside the cfquery tags, with any ifs/switches/etc as appropriate, and ensure **all** CF variables use the `cfqueryparam` tag.

(Note, if you use variables in the ORDER BY clause, you'll need to manually escape any variables; cfqueryparam can't be used in ORDER BY clauses)

Answer (score 4):

ColdFusion automatically escapes single quotes quotes in `<cfquery>` tags when you use the following syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Foo='#Foo#'
```

In case you would want to preserve single quotes in `#Foo#` you must call `#PreserveSingleQuotes(Foo)#`.

Be aware the the automatic escaping works only for variable values, not for function results.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Foo='#LCase(Foo)#' /* Single quotes are retained! */
```

In that light, the function `PreserveSingleQuotes()` (see [Adobe LiveDocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/6.1/htmldocs/functa53.htm)) is not much more than a "null operation" on the value - turning it into a function result to bypass auto-escaping.

Answer (score 0):

I voted up Dave's answer since I thought he did a good job.

I'd like to add however that there are also several different tools designed for ColdFusion that can simplify a lot of the common SQL tasks you're likely to perform. There's a very light-weight tool called [DataMgr](http://datamgr.riaforge.org/) written by Steve Bryant, as well as [Transfer](http://www.transfer-orm.com) from Mark Mandel, [Reactor](http://www.reactorframework.com) which was originally created by Doug Hughes and one I developed called [DataFaucet](http://www.datafaucet.com). Each of these has its own strengths and weaknesses. Personally I think you're apt to consider DataFaucet to be the one that will give you the best ability to stay in cfscript, with a variety of syntaxes for building different kinds of queries.

Here are a few examples:

```
qry = datasource.select_avg_price_as_avgprice_from_products(); //(requires CF8)

qry = datasource.select("avg(price) as avgprice","products"); 

qry = datasource.getSelect("avg(price) as  avgprice","products").filter("categoryid",url.categoryid).execute();

qry = datasource.getSelect(table="products",orderby="productname").filter("categoryid",url.categoryid).execute();
```

The framework ensures that cfqueryparam is always used with these filter statements to prevent sql-injection attacks, and there are similar syntaxes for insert, update and delete statements. (There are a couple of [simple rules to avoid sql-injection](http://datafaucet.wikispaces.com/SQL+Injection).)