# CFQUERY Not escaping single quotes properly

Tags: coldfusion, escaping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Coldfusion adding extra quotes when constructing database queries in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266586/coldfusion-adding-extra-quotes-when-constructing-database-queries-in-strings)

All,

I am trying to use a getter to reference a bean during an insert. CF is not escaping the single quote properly in the value in 'form.title' and therefore I am receiving a malformed sql error.

Any ideas?

Here's the code.

```
<cfscript>
form.title = "page's are awesome";

page = new model.page.page(argumentCollection = form);
```

```
<cfquery name="test" datasource="ksurvey">
insert into page(title)
values('#page.getTitle()#')
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're going to do it that way, you need preserveSingleQuotes()

`INSERT INTO page( title ) 
VALUES ( '#preserveSingleQuotes( page.getTitle() )#' )`

Of course, insert the standard caveat about how you should be using cfqueryparam to avoid SQL injection attacks.

`INSERT INTO page( title ) 
VALUES ( <cfqueryparam value="#page.getTitle()#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" /> )`

For reference:

- http://cfquickdocs.com/cf9/#preservesinglequotes
- http://cfquickdocs.com/cf9/#cfqueryparam

Comment: Hey Charlie, thanks much for the quick response.

As it always seems to be, I figured this out shortly after posting. I was trying queryparam and preservesinglequotes and was refreshing my app, but no luck. Figured I was passing refresh instead of reload in the URL, doh! 

Marking your answer right though because it is in fact the answer to my question :)

Need more coffee! - Thanks

Comment: The site `cfquickdocks dot com` seems gone - look at https://cfdocs.org/preservesinglequotes

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't insert any value into a database without using cfqueryparam, its not safe!  Not only that but cfqueryparam will handle all the escaping for you.

```
<cfquery name="test" datasource="ksurvey">
   insert into 
       page(title)
   values(<cfqueryparam value="#page.getTitle()#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">);
</cfquery>
```